# Regex syntax for a string containing only [a-zA-Z0-9.-_] with max length of 20 and cannot end with a '.' and can only contain at most two '.'

Tags: regex

### Issue

I cannot get the regex syntax down for the following conditions:

- Length 1-20
- Can only contain the following chars `a-zA-Z0-9.-_`
- Cannot end with a `.`
- Can only have 0, 1, or 2 occurrences of a `.`

---

### Input

#### Pass

The following items should pass the regex validation

```
dummy.txt
dummy.tar.gz
.dummy
```

#### Fail

The following items should fail the regex validation

```
dummy.
dummy.dummy.tar.gz
dummydummydummy.tar.gz
```

1. Ends with `.`
2. More than 2 `.`
3. More than 20 characters

---

### Attempts

Here's the syntax I have so far, which works, but I can't figure out how to add the "no more than two `.`" constraint:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,20}(?<!\.)$
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should use `Negative Lookahead (?!)`

Comment: *"and can only contain at most two '.'"* is not something that `regex` is designed to do. This doesn't mean it's impossible, it means only this is not a job for `regex`. There are other, simpler and more elegant ways to accomplish this goal.

Comment: @axiac You are correct that there are other more elegant ways of making those checks, but regex does allow - and is designed - to perform such tasks. `(?!(?:.*\.){3,})` does exactly this.

Comment: @ctwheels `(?!(?:[^.]*\.){3})` is faster and good enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, I've updated my answer to incorporate that code (with proper citation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Brief

Since you didn't specify a regex flavour, I'll assume anything goes.

---

### Code

[See code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/YTQyek/2/)

**Version 1**

```
^(?!(?:.*\.){3,})[\w.-]{1,20}(?<!\.)$
```

**Version 2:** As provided by [@WiktorStribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) the following regex will perform better (change made to negative lookahead).

```
^(?!(?:[^.]*\.){3})[\w.-]{1,20}(?<!\.)$
```

**Note:** The above regex will not work if pasted into the same project in regex101 (link above **Version 1**) unless you change `[^.]` to `[^\r\n.]` due to the nature of the character set negation and line separator characters in the IDE.

Explanation of changes:

- `[^.]` Any character not present in the set (any character except `.`)
- `{3}` As pointed out by Wiktor, this will suffice, no need to check for any further matches

---

### Results

#### Input

```
dummy.txt
dummy.tar.gz
.dummy

dummy.
dummy.dummy.tar.gz
dummydummydummy.tar.gz
```

#### Output

**Note:** Only matches are shown hereafter

```
dummy.txt
dummy.tar.gz
.dummy
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of line
- `(?!(?:.*\.){3,})` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows does not match

  - `(?:.*\..*){3,}` Match the following 3 or more times

    - `.*\.` Match any character any number of times, followed by a dot `.` literally
- `[\w.-]{1,20}` Match any character present in the set (any word character `a-zA-Z0-9_`, the dot character `.` literally, or the hyphen-minus character `-` literally) between 1 and 20 times
- `(?<!\.)` Negative lookbehind ensuring what preceded doesn't match the following

  - `\.` The dot character `.` literally
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

---

### Additional Notes

As per [@RoryO'Kane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578288/rory-okane) `\w` may match non-ASCII characters from other scripts.
You may want to replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` if you want to ensure only ASCII characters are matched.

The below quotation was pulled from [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

> `\w` stands for "word character". It always matches the ASCII
>   characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and
>   digits. In most flavors that support Unicode, `\w` includes many
>   characters from other scripts. There is a lot of inconsistency about
>   which characters are actually included. Letters and digits from
>   alphabetic scripts and ideographs are generally included. Connector
>   punctuation other than the underscore and numeric symbols that aren't
>   digits may or may not be included. XML Schema and XPath even include
>   all symbols in `\w`. Again, Java, JavaScript, and PCRE match only
>   ASCII characters with `\w`.

Comment: In some regex flavors `\w` matches not just `a-zA-Z0-9_`, but also other characters such as `é`. Thus, I suggest writing the ranges out explicitly in a character class `[]`.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Thanks, I've added a note at the end of my answer to include this information